# How to clear https proxy setting of NPM?

Tags: node.js, proxy

How can I clear the previous ssl proxy setting of NPM? 
well, I search a lot, but all post I got is mainly about how to `set` proxy in corporate network.

I try to set proxy to nothing:

```
npm config set http-proxy
npm config set https-proxy
```

the first command pass yet the second one warn that:

```
npm WARN invalid config proxy=""
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
```

is the warning neglectable and I have successfully clear the proxy setting?

Comment: You can manually delete proxy settings from `<user_dir>/.npmrc` file

Answer (score 525):

None of the above helped me, but this did:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Source: http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.ch/2013/11/set-and-reset-proxy-for-git-and-npm.html

Comment: Works on windows

Comment: Can use `npm config list` to check the proxy config, maybe `npm config rm http-proxy` is needed, too

Comment: @Anatolii has an answer for cleaning up **global** configuration settings below.  The `rm` parameter doesn't work on old versions of `npm` for Windows -- see @Aaron's answer below.

Answer (score 158):

Try deleting them with:

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Comment: It outputs the same warning.

Comment: shouldn't it be npm config delete proxy?

Comment: This work on windows. Try `npm config rm http-proxy` on linux

Answer (score 49):

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
unset HTTP_PROXY
unset HTTPS_PROXY
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Damn finally this does the trick in Debian Jessie with privoxy (ad remover) installed, Thank you :-)

Comment: This was the correct solution on OSX 10.11, tried everything else

Comment: This solution works but doesn't seem to stick, after logout / reboot I had the same issue again.  Can anyone explain where these variables are getting set? @privoxyd

Answer (score 43):

This was already answered but I think the `--global` config is not covered properly.

By running `npm config rm proxy` you remove proxy from **user configuration**.
 This can be easily verified by running: `npm config list`.
If there is `proxy` or `https-proxy` setting set in global config you have to use `--global` in the command to remove it.

So at the end this will clean-up proxies from both local and global configs:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config --global rm proxy
npm config --global rm https-proxy
```

Comment: This --global thing did the trick for me while just removing from the user configuration had no effect. Running on an old NPM version though. #thanksanatolii

Answer (score 31):

In the latest version `npm rm proxy` does not work. Instead use `npm rm http-proxy`

`npm config rm proxy
 npm config rm https-proxy`

Answer (score 29):

By the default value `npm` is looking for packages from `https://registry.npmjs.org`. What you also need to do is override the `registry` and `strict-ssl` values.

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to overcome the whole issue of npm behind proxies.

Comment: Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 22):

I have used the below commands for removing any proxy set:

```
    npm config rm proxy
    npm config rm https-proxy
```

And it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 21):

If you go through the [npm config documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html), it says:

> **proxy**
>
> Default: HTTP_PROXY or http_proxy environment variable, **or
>   null**
>
> Type: url

As per this, to disable usage of proxy, `proxy` setting must be set to `null`. To set proxy value to null, one has to make sure that `HTTP_PROXY` or `http_proxy` environment variable is not set. So unset these environment variables and make sure that `npm config ls -l` shows `proxy = null`.

Also, it is important to note that:

- Deleting http_proxy and https_proxy config settings alone will not
  help if you still have HTTP_PROXY or http_proxy environment variable
  is set to something and
- Setting registry to use http:// and setting
  strict-ssl to false will not help you if you are not behind a proxy
  anyway and have HTTP_PROXY set to something.

It would have been better if npm had made the type of proxy setting to boolean to switch on/off the proxy usage. Or, they can introduce a new setting of sort `use_proxy` of type boolean.

Comment: This helped me, all the other suggestions (`delete` & `rm`) only remove `https-proxy` & `proxy` settings for your local npm config - **not** the default, by setting null it overrides these default settings

Comment: npm 3 does not honor `--proxy=null` anymore, does anyone know details?

Comment: To answer my own question, `--no-proxy` seems to work

Comment: @C-Otto Thank you so much for writing the only answer that worked after hours of banging my head!

Comment: @C-Otto Thank you so much. This is the only solution which worked for me. I tried hundreds of other solution but nothing worked. '--no-proxy' did the trick. But do you know why does it pick old proxy settings without '--no-proxy' option and from where?

Answer (score 17):

there is a simple way of deleting or removing the npm proxies.

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem once.
Follow these steps to delete proxy values:

1.To delete proxy in npm:
(-g is Important)
`npm config delete proxy -g`
`npm config delete http-proxy -g`
`npm config delete https-proxy -g`

Check the npm config file using:
`npm config list`

2.To delete system proxy:
`set HTTP_PROXY=null` 
`set HTTPS_PROXY=null`

Now close the command line and open it to refresh the variables(proxy).

Answer (score 15):

Nothing above worked for me. I had to edit the file ".npmrc" which will be under user home directory (ex: c:\users\abcuser) :

```
http_proxy=null
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=true
proxy=null
```

Comment: This Worked for me...  To remove proxy we have to change registry as https://registry.npmjs.org/ and strict-ssl as true

Comment: I am trying this out to see if my project specific .npmrc setting for proxy will override any global settings in the user's home dir which clobber us in a shared build environment.

Comment: I updated my project .nprmc file. It did not work

Answer (score 14):

This works

```
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

set HTTP_PROXY=null
set HTTPS_PROXY=null
```

Answer (score 13):

Running npm version 2.10.1 in windows 7, I used:

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Answer (score 11):

Try This,

npm config delete http-proxy

npm config delete https-proxy

npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy

set HTTP_PROXY=null

set HTTPS_PROXY=null

Comment: If you're using bash (Linux, or Window Git bash), try `export HTTP_PROXY=` and `export HTTPS_PROXY=` rather than `set ...=null`

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to remove any configuration at all from npm is to edit the npm config file. It only takes two(2) commands to do this; one to open npm config file for editing, the other to confirm your change.

1. type `npm config list` to view a  list of all npm configurations that are active.
2. type `npm config edit` to open a text editor with npm configurations. 
   To remove the proxy line ( or simply comment it out ).
3. Save the config file and close it.
4. type `npm config list` to confirm that the proxy configuration has been removed.

C'est la vie!

I tried everything listed on this page, none worked, then I tried to the config edit. It worked instantly. (I use Windows 10)

Comment: @Madhan it is the Swiss Army knife for npm configuration

Answer (score 8):

```
npm config delete proxy -g
```

worked for me.

`-g` was important as initially it was set with that option.
You can check configurations set with :

```
npm config list
```

Comment: npm write config also on ./etc

Answer (score 6):

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I think it's not http-proxy but proxy:

```
npm config set proxy="http://yourproxyhere"
```

Comment: It always showed  
`npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the`  
`npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'`  
None of the other options worked. This one worked best.

Answer (score 3):

Got exactly the same problem, I keep seeing my proxy configuration even after removing the npmrc file and deleting the keys.

I found out that npm were using windows env key http-proxy by default.

So go in Computer->Properties->Advanced system settings->Environement variables and check there is no http-proxy key configured.

Comment: Interesting, I checked the environment variables and I don't have things like `http-proxy`. Maybe the warning is really neglectable.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Linux Mint 16 based on Ubuntu), I had to:

1. `npm config delete https-proxy`, and also
2. clear the `https_proxy` Bash environment parameter — oddly enough, although I cannot find this behavior documented anywhere, npm fallbacks to `https_proxy`:

   ```
   $ http_proxy='' https_proxy='' npm config get https-proxy
   null
   $ http_proxy='' xxhttps_proxy='' npm config get https-proxy
   https://1.2.3.4:8080
   ```

Answer (score 3):

See the npm Settings in file `C:\Users\myusers.npmrc` file. Sometime the npm proxy config settings does not apply. so its worth checking in there.

Answer (score 3):

```
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

npm config delete proxy -g
npm config delete http-proxy -g
```

then

```
npm config get proxy
```

> null

also

```
npm i -g bower to update
```

npm had a bug on the proxy

Answer (score 3):

If you want to switch between proxy for company network and remove proxy for home/personal network you can use `--no-proxy`

Sample usage:

```
npm install --save-dev "@angular/animations@8.2.14" --no-proxy
```

Answer (score 2):

execute npm config list
it will list down all proxy values.. in my case proxy value was fetched form global npmrc file, removed it and was able to complete npm install on my windows machine

Comment: I removed proxy in Global .nprmc . I started getting 407 Error. I was behind corporate proxy

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm gonna leave this here because I was having a big trouble with NPM.

I was trying to change a proxy setting using `npm config set proxy "http://.../"` and then running `npm config get proxy`. It was ALWAYS returning a wrong value, different from the one that I'd set.

I found out that I had a `.npmrc` COMMITED on the project I was trying to run `npm install` and that this file was overriding my own config.

So it was cleaning the proxy value, but I needed to also change the `.npmrc` inside the folder's project.

After that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've used

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
```

and it worked for me.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

this works for me fime

```
proxy=http://<username>:<pass>@proxyhost:<port>

https-proxy=http://<uname>:<pass>@proxyhost:<port>
```

sample in my instance username:uname and password:pword

```
npm config set proxy=http://uname:pword@192.168.5.8:8080

npm config set https-proxy=http://uname:pword@192.168.5.8:8080
```

Comment: This is setting, we are looking for clear which is exact opposite

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for ages. What I finally did was go into the .npmrc file (which can be found in the user's directory followed by the user's name, ie. C:\Users\erikj/.npmrc), opened it with a text editor, manually removed any proxy settings and changed the http:// setting to https://. In this case, it is a matter of experimenting whether http or https will work for you. In my case, https worked. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, (windows OS), after put all those commands listed, npm kept taking
the proxy in the setting of windows registry

\ HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Environment

just remove the proxy settings there, after that, I restarted the pc and then "npm install" worked for me

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vadvU.png)

Answer (score 1):

First, type:

```
npm config get
```

If you see any config about a proxy, you can delete that with the name of its key.
In my case I had a line: `registry = "http://172.16.10.54:4777"`
I deleted it with the command:

```
npm config delete registry
```

And that worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Http Module is **deprecated** and it is replaced with HttpClient.

Change your imports to `import { HttpClientModule }`  from `'@angular/common/http';`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
Step 1:

> env |grep proxy
> e.g,I got:
> http_proxy
> https_proxy

Step2:
unset the proxy variables

> unset http_proxy
> unset https_proxy

Then npm install works ok now

Answer (score 0):

this will clean-up proxies from both local and global configs without --global it will clear only from the current user profile:

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config --global rm proxy
npm config --global rm https-proxy

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the `proxy` and `https-proxy` manually from the `.npmrc` file

Answer (score 0):

If you like to disable proxy settings just temporarily, then run

```
npm --noproxy "registry.npmjs.org" install <package>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will get the proxy host and port from your server administrator or support.

After that set up

npm config set http_proxy http://username:password@proxyofmycomp.com:itsport
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxyofmycomp.com:itsport
If there any special character in password try with % urlencode. Eg:- pound(hash) shuold be replaced by %23.

This worked for me...

Answer (score -1):

ok, "NPM config delete ..." is the right command for Windows environment, viceversa "NPM config rm ..." it is for Unix-like environment.
Moreover, at least for me, it was mandatory to add the option "-g" because the command worked properly