# installing Ionic Framework in node js

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I am getting an error when installing Ionic framework in node js. I am behind a proxy but I already set-up my node config to a proper proxy.

Here is the error message:

> error network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=read
>   ECONNRESET error network This is most likely not a problem with npm
>   itself error network and is related to network connectivity. error
>   network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network
>   settings. error network error network If you are behind a proxy,
>   please make sure that the error network 'proxy' config is set
>   properly.  See: 'npm help confi

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue in the end?

Comment: Already answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574204/installing-ionic-framework-in-node-js/31125304#31125304

Answer (score 0):

Try installing older version of Node(0.10.38).

Already answere here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31124491/1276616

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

1) Check if u have a proxy

```
npm config get proxy
```

2) If u have, remove them

```
npm config rm proxy 
npm config rm https-proxy
```

I hope be useful.

Source: [How clear proxy npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228995/how-to-clear-https-proxy-setting-of-npm)