# Error when trying to install anything using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm learning node.js with learnyounode tutorial. Several times it has asked me to install something like bl,through2-map, etc. Every time I type: npm install through2-map --save

It will run for a few minutes then throw this error

```
 Linux 4.2.0-c9
npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.1/bin/npm" "install" "through2-map" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:15443
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:15443]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 15443 }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/workspace/npm-debug.log
```

I tried to follow this stackoverflow suggestion [npm install not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244684/npm-install-not-work)
but that did not work. So can someone help me solve how to set my npm so that I can install these modules. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if you need to be using a proxy server or not? This [question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21228995/398606) show how you can set or remove the proxy setting.  If you don't know whether or not you need to use a proxy server, you probably don't... and should remove the value and go back to trouble shooting the original problem you had.

Comment: Ok thank you for the link I was able to remove the proxy, I definitely did not know so removing it was a good choice, when I check it now says null for that. But back to npm install through2-map I now get the error above.

Answer (score 1):

Your NPM registry is not set to https://registry.npmjs.org anymore:

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```