# issue installing npm packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

hello guys I'm facing a problem with npm. I can't install any package and whenever I try to install  any package it throws this error

> ```
> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-5.7.1.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> ```

Comment: add your `package.json` file

Comment: Try removing npm proxy configuration https://stackoverflow.com/a/24910317/5779083

Comment: thanks a lot that solved the problem