# npm install -g create-react-app give errors

Tags: reactjs, npm

[This is errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUWSB.png)
This is the error's that i'm getting while typing npm install -g create-react-app, robofriend is the name of my app that i'm suppose to create
And Thanx for your help in advance

Comment: Looks like you've set a proxy for npm (proxy.company.com) that is not reachable from your current network

Comment: so which proxy i have to set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear https proxy setting of NPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228995/how-to-clear-https-proxy-setting-of-npm)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If that work then Yes!

Answer (score 0):

> Go to directory from project file and write:

```
npm install -g create-react-app project_name
```

> Or:

```
npx create-react-app project_name
```

Comment: npm install -g create-react-app not working giving me a network error